# How can I add a whitespace in between my element and psuedo element?

Tags: html, css

I'm using the ::before selector to add an image before each list item in my menu, and I just want to add a blank space in between the image and the text. here is the markup

```
<ul>
   <li>menu 1</li>
   <li>menu 2</li>
   <li>menu 3</li>
</ul>
```

& the CSS

```
&::before {
        content: url("plus.png");
    }
```

I've tried

```
  &::before {
        content: url("plus.png") + "\00a0";
    }
```

And

```
&::before {
        content: url("plus.png" + "\00a0" );
    }
```

Any ideas of how to accomplish this? Thanks!

Comment: Why not use `margin-right`? [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zaup46j9/)

Comment: Using a margin is the best way to do this with pure html & css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
&::before {
    content: url("plus.png");
    margin-right: 10px;
}

<ul>
     <li>menu 1</li>
     <li>menu 2</li>
     <li>menu 3</li>
</ul>
```

Using the margin command makes whitespace around the element.

Comment: Yes that worked thanks, now another question, if I am using a "border-bottom" on the hover state, how can I just underline the text and not the image/pseudo element? Is this possible?

Comment: you can use the <u></u> tag around the text

Answer (score 1):

Use margin-right instead.

```css
li::before {
    content: url("http://placehold.it/10x10");
    margin-right: 5px;
}
li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>menu 1</li>
    <li>menu 2</li>
    <li>menu 3</li>
</ul>
```